# Geometry Nodes: Points going down the drain

Tags: geometry-nodes

How would you go about making this with Geometry Nodes? Mainly to get the points (arrows) go in that way, but also preferably to have the exact orientation as the arrows as well.

Is the best way to just make a lot of curves manually that follow the surface and use trim curve? (I'll try that now)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this got me at least half the way... but not fully to an infinite loop.

[image]

And yes, a lot of manually made curves...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps adding a modulo between Random Value and Trim Curve with a value of 22 in the divisor will do the trick?